# What is Youtube Developer Key?Where I can find it in Google Developer console?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have registered project in GoogleDeveloper console.I can see a window with tabs API and Auth,Apis ,Credentials,Push,Monitoring,Consent Scrren etc..I have switched on Google YouTube Data API v3.Where i can find Youtube Developer key?Is client id same as Developer key?

Comment: The key is the same if you enabled Google YouTube Data API v3. Just go the Credentials in your project and it's under `Key for Android applications`

Comment: I have used "Create New Client id" option for registering project..There is field named "Client id"..is it the developer key?Or i need to use option "Create new key"?

Comment: When you creater your client id make sure you check Installed application. Then select Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your key needed for android youtube api is the "Key for Android applications"
This is a Public API acces. You need to "Create new Key" as a "Android Key".

When did you activate this feature ? (the key could be given later ?)

[image]

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

After Creating the project go to **API'S** AND **Auth** then go to **credentials** you will find the developer key

Comment: I found "Client Id" for application..is it same as developer key?I don't find any field named "Developer Key"

Comment: I have used "Create New Client id" option for registering project..There is field named "Client id"..is it the developer key?I don't see any field names "API KEY".Do i need to use option "Create new key"?

Answer (score 0):

No, **Client id** and **Developer key** both are different.

**Proof »** The MATLAB code available under the **Functions** tab of this webpage [MATLAB - Upload video to YouTube](https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19258-upload-a-video-to-youtube%E2%84%A2) uses **Client ID** and **Developer key** both.

Below is the fragment of that code which  shows it:

```
% Define needed variables.
username = getPrefOrPrompt('Username');
password = getPrefOrPrompt('Password');
developerKey = 'AI39si7J7QPwNZriOcSa6z2wpbYbN2pFgI9Xdvv4EYSq84SssGa9pB_UwNmaXYiCVXA';
clientid = 'ytapi-MatthewSimoneau-YouTubeUploadfro-ge7j8nsn-0';

% Upload the file.
service = YouTubeService(clientid, developerKey);
```

If you will visit [Google Cloud platform - API credentials page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and select your application. You will see 3 things **Client ID**, **Client secret** and **Creation date** as the below image shows.

[image]

So in my opinion, **Client secret** is your **Developer key** and **Client ID** is your **Client id**. Once try it and comment, if really it is.